# ValueError when creating Siamese network using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to use Siamese Network to figure out if two inputs are identical or not. Following is the brief summary of Siamese network:

> A siamese network is a network consisting of two identical neural
>   networks with tied weights (the weights of the two networks are the
>   same). Given two inputs X_1 and X_2, X_1 is fed to the first network
>   and X_2 to the second network. Then, the outputs from the two networks
>   are combined and produce an answer to the question: are the two inputs
>   similar or different?

I have created the following network using tensorflow, but I am getting errors.

```
graph = tf.Graph()

# Add nodes to the graph
with graph.as_default():
    with tf.variable_scope('siamese_network') as scope:
        labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='labels')
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='question1_keep_prob')

        question1_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='question1_inputs')

        question1_embedding = tf.get_variable(name='embedding', initializer=tf.random_uniform((n_words, embed_size), -1, 1))
        question1_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(question1_embedding, question1_inputs)

        question1_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
        question1_drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(question1_lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
        question1_multi_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([question1_drop] * lstm_layers)

        initial_state = question1_multi_lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

        question1_outputs, question1_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(question1_multi_lstm, question1_embed, initial_state=initial_state, scope='question1_siamese')
        question1_predictions = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(question1_outputs[:, -1], 1, activation_fn=tf.sigmoid)

        scope.reuse_variables()

        question2_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='question2_inputs')

        question2_embedding = tf.get_variable(name='embedding', initializer=tf.random_uniform((n_words, embed_size), -1, 1))
        question2_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(question2_embedding, question2_inputs)

        question2_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
        question2_drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(question2_lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
        question2_multi_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([question2_drop] * lstm_layers)

        question2_outputs, question2_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(question2_multi_lstm, question2_embed, initial_state=initial_state)
        question2_predictions = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(question2_outputs[:, -1], 1, activation_fn=tf.sigmoid)
```

I am getting following error at following line:

```
question2_outputs, question2_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(question2_multi_lstm, question2_embed, initial_state=initial_state)
```

Here is the error:

```
ValueError: Variable siamese_network/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, 
or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

**SOLUTION**

The issue was in the following line:

```
question1_outputs, question1_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(question1_multi_lstm, question1_embed, initial_state=initial_state, scope='question1_siamese')
```

I had to only remove the `scope` attribute and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
scope.reuse_variables()
```

you are telling tensorflow that variables used later are already declared and should be reused. However your Siamese network share some, but not all, variables; more precisely, `question2_outputs`, `question2_final_stat` and `question2_predictions` are unique to your second network and do not reuse weights.

In your current code, because everything is layed out flat, you do actually not need to call `reuse_variables`, you could simply write

```
question2_embedding = question1_embedding
```

and you should be fine. `reuse_variables` comes handy when you start encapsulating your common network in a function. You could write something like

```
with tf.variable_scope('siamese_common') as scope:
  net1 = siamese_common(question1_input)
  scope.reuse_variables()
  net2 = siamese_common(question2_input)
```

to get the common part upon which you plug the respective outputs of your first and second network.

Comment: The reason I used `reuse_variables()` is because the Siamese network requires the weights to be same in both the networks.

Comment: Yes, and by writing `question2_embedding = question1_embedding` you achieve just that.